# How can I upload KML file into Fusion Table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Is it possible to upload a KML file into a Fusion Table programmatically?
I am not familiar with Fusion Tables. So, Can anyone please help me import KML files into a Fusion Table using JavaScript, Asp.Net and C#?

Comment: Need help on same topic. 
Need to upload data of file more than 250MB on fusion tables., in php or js etc.